# Angular 6: How to implement a progress bar under the horizontal header-navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4, progress-bar, angular6, gradient

I would like to implement a horizontal progress bar under a navbar.  [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOEGf.png)

There are two forms that will open when the user clicks on the navbar-links. Once the first form is filled out and submitted, the progress should be displayed in the progress bar. The same applies form the second form.

How can I achieve this using angular6 and bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [bootstrap progress bars](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp), angular material [progress bars](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) or [progress bars using svg](https://css-tricks.com/animated-svg-radial-progress-bars/). Here's a [how to](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp) from w3schools.

You could use css and apply the according class (0%, 50% or 100% completion) via ngClass for example..

But don't expect anyone to code that for you..